# QProcess can not find the file specified

Tags: c++, qt

I want to start a `QProcess` to execute an `.exe` file in the working directory with some arguments. The error string says that the specified file is not found indeed the executable is already in the working directory.

The output of the process under Win10 is:

```
workingDirectory: "\"C:\\devApp\\Build\\tmp\""
program: "dcmodify.exe"
arguments: (" -q", " -ie", " -gin", " -nb", " -ma", " (0010,0010)=na", " *.dcm")
error: "Process failed to start: system can not find the file specified."
```

If I execute same commands on the `cmd` I have no problems, such:

```
cd /d "C:\\devApp\\Build\\Tmp\" && dcmodify.exe -q -ie -gin -nb -ma (0010,0010)=na *.dcm
```

This is my code

```
QString workingDirectory =
  QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::cleanPath(Utilities::getAppPath() +
    QDir::separator() +
    toQString("Build") +
    QDir::separator() +
    toQString("tmp") +
    QDir::separator()));

QString executable = toQString("dcmodify.exe");

QStringList parameters;
parameters << 
toQString(" -q") <<
toQString(" -ie") <<
toQString(" -gin") <<
toQString(" -nb") <<
toQString(" -ma") <<
toQString(" (0010,0010)=na") <<
toQString(" *.dcm"); 

QProcess *proc = new QProcess(this);
  proc->setWorkingDirectory(workingDirectory);
  proc->setProgram(executable);
  proc->setArguments(parameters);
  proc->start();

  bool retval = false;
  while (retval = proc->waitForFinished());

  if (!retval) 
  {
    qDebug() << "workingDirectory:" << proc->workingDirectory();
    qDebug() << "program:" << proc->program();
    qDebug() << "arguments:" << proc->arguments();
    qDebug() << "error:" << proc->errorString();
  }
```

Comment: `workingDirectory` should not have the double-quotes. They will be considered as part of the actual path name.

Comment: `QProcess` adds them itself. I removed the quotes `toQString("\"")` from `QString workingDirectory`. The output is still `"C:\\devApp\\Build\\Tmp\"`

Comment: How do you output the working directory? The quotes may be added for display purposes, but they shouldn't be in the actual path in your program.

Comment: Using `QDebug()` How could I remove them?

Comment: I mean don't add them when you define and initialize the `workingDirectory` variable. If `qDebug()` add them for display purposes that's one thing, they just shouldn't be in the path variable `workingDirectory` to begin with.

Comment: I did it already. Please see my edited code. The error does not change

Comment: It's entirely possible that `QProcess` doesn't look in the working directory you set for the executable program. Use e.g. `workingDirectory + QDir::separator() + "dcmodify.exe"` for the program name.

Comment: It gives me an `unknown error`

Comment: Your while(retval = waitForFinished()) makes no sense. It will wait for the process to finish (or 30sec t/o), and in case it did finish sucessfully (retval = true) it will try again (while) until the process somehow doesnt finish. It cannot be unfinished after it finished. You should at least invert the logic; **while(!retval)** and make sure to check the error every time in this loop!